# Gulp build : unexpected token at 1:0

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am creating angular-gulp project. And trying to run the gulp build command and minify my HTML.

But always getting following error

```
    { SyntaxError: C:/Users/me/Desktop/ABC1/client/src/app/amenities/amenities.html: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | <div class="amenitiespage" hm-swiperight="amenities.prevAmenity()" hm-swipeleft="amenities.nextAmenity()" hm-manager-options="amenities.hammerConf" hm-recognizer-options="[{'type':'swipe', 'directions':'DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL'}]">
    | ^
  2 |   <div class="amenitybox">
  3 |     <div class="amenity" ng-repeat="amenity in amenities.amenities" ng-show="amenities.isCurrent($index)" ng-class="{fromright: amenities.fromRight, fromleft: amenities.fromLeft, hidden: amenities.isHidden($index)}">
  4 |       <div class="image" id-width="amenity.width" id-height="amenity.height" id-center-left="amenity.left" id-center-top="amenity.top" id-show="amenity.init" imgdraggable >
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3750:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3306:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1906:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1778:8)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1673:17)
    at parse (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:7305:37)
    at File.parse (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:527:15)
    at File.parseCode (C:\Users\me\Desktop\ABC1\client\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:612:20)
  pos: 0,
  loc: Position { line: 1, column: 0 },
  _babel: true,
  codeFrame: '\u001b[0m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 1 | \u001b[39m\u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenitiespage"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mswiperight\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.prevAmenity()"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mswipeleft\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.nextAmenity()"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mmanager\u001b[33m-\u001b[39moptions\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.hammerConf"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mrecognizer\u001b[33m-\u001b[39moptions\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"[{\'type\':\'swipe\', \'directions\':\'DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL\'}]"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m   | \u001b[39m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m^\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 2 | \u001b[39m  \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenitybox"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 3 | \u001b[39m    \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mrepeat\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity in amenities.amenities"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mshow\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.isCurrent($index)"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39m\u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"{fromright: amenities.fromRight, fromleft: amenities.fromLeft, hidden: amenities.isHidden($index)}"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 4 | \u001b[39m      \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"image"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mwidth\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.width"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mheight\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.height"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mcenter\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mleft\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.left"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mcenter\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mtop\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.top"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mshow\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.init"\u001b[39m imgdraggable \u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\u001b[0m',
  name: 'SyntaxError',
  message: 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/ABC1/client/src/app/amenities/amenities.html: Unexpected token (1:0)',
  stack: 'SyntaxError: C:/Users/me/Desktop/ABC1/client/src/app/amenities/amenities.html: Unexpected token (1:0)\n\u001b[0m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 1 | \u001b[39m\u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenitiespage"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mswiperight\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.prevAmenity()"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mswipeleft\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.nextAmenity()"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mmanager\u001b[33m-\u001b[39moptions\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.hammerConf"\u001b[39m hm\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mrecognizer\u001b[33m-\u001b[39moptions\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"[{\'type\':\'swipe\', \'directions\':\'DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL\'}]"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m   | \u001b[39m\u001b[31m\u001b[1m^\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 2 | \u001b[39m  \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenitybox"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 3 | \u001b[39m    \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mrepeat\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity in amenities.amenities"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mshow\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenities.isCurrent($index)"\u001b[39m ng\u001b[33m-\u001b[39m\u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"{fromright: amenities.fromRight, fromleft: amenities.fromLeft, hidden: amenities.isHidden($index)}"\u001b[39m\u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m 4 | \u001b[39m      \u001b[33m<\u001b[39m\u001b[33mdiv\u001b[39m \u001b[36mclass\u001b[39m\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"image"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mwidth\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.width"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mheight\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.height"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mcenter\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mleft\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.left"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mcenter\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mtop\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.top"\u001b[39m id\u001b[33m-\u001b[39mshow\u001b[33m=\u001b[39m\u001b[32m"amenity.init"\u001b[39m imgdraggable \u001b[33m>\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:4454:13)\n    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:1761:8)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3750:12)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3494:19)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3474:19)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3404:19)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3381:19)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3344:19)\n    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:3306:19)\n    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:1906:19)\n    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:2268:21)\n    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:1778:8)\n    at Parser.parse (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:1673:17)\n    at parse (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\index.js:7305:37)\n    at File.parse (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\index.js:527:15)\n    at File.parseCode (C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\index.js:612:20)',
  fileName: 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\ABC1\\client\\src\\app\\amenities\\amenities.html',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: false,
  plugin: 'gulp-babel' }
```

I am working on Windows with following versions
NodeJS :8.7.0
NPM : 5.4.2
gulp : CLI -3.5.6
       Local - 3.9.1

I am unable to found any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Following is my HTML:

```
<div class="amenitiespage" hm-swiperight="amenities.prevAmenity()" hm-swipeleft="amenities.nextAmenity()" hm-manager-options="amenities.hammerConf" hm-recognizer-options="[{'type':'swipe', 'directions':'DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL'}]">
  <div class="amenitybox">
    <div class="amenity" ng-repeat="amenity in amenities.amenities" ng-show="amenities.isCurrent($index)" ng-class="{fromright: amenities.fromRight, fromleft: amenities.fromLeft, hidden: amenities.isHidden($index)}">
      <div class="image" id-width="amenity.width" id-height="amenity.height" id-center-left="amenity.left" id-center-top="amenity.top" id-show="amenity.init" imgdraggable >
        <img alt="{{amenity.name}}" ng-src="{{amenity.image}}"/>
        <div class="abg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h3 ng-bind="amenity.toptext"></h3>
        <h2 ng-bind="amenity.name"></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="discover" ng-click="amenities.toggleWhiteBox()" ng-class="{close: amenities.showWhiteBox}">
    <div class="icon">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prev" ng-click="amenities.prevAmenity()"></div>
  <div class="next" ng-click="amenities.nextAmenity()"></div>
  <div class="white-box" ng-show="amenities.showWhiteBox">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="poi in amenities.getCurrentPois()" ng-bind-html="poi.text"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

gulp code:

```
gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ]).pipe(errorHandler(logError))
  .pipe(babel({presets:['env']}))  
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'client',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  const partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  const partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  const htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  const jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  const cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.{html,xml}'))
 .pipe(errorHandler(logError))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    //.pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    //.pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });

gulp.task('build', ['html']);
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: please check,.. i have added html in  my post

Comment: And can you show your gulp code?

Comment: @hurricane please check gulp code

Comment: You need to check  js functions for js files and html functions for html files.

Comment: @hurricane .. is there any issue in my code.. totally stuck with this task.
Need to deliver it today

Comment: My guess is that your file is a UTF8 file starting with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: @JBNizet what would be my approach then.. I don't know much about BOM

Comment: Open the file wth a good text editor telling you if it has a BOM or not (or with a hex editor allowing to see that), and remove the BOM if it's present.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't found anything wrong with html

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue